# ¿Como puedo integrar y comenzar a hacer pagos con el Mobile Checkout de Mercado pago en mi app de android?

Tags: java, android-studio, mercadopago, checkout

Estoy tratando de iniciar un Flujo de pago de prueba de mercado pago en mi app Android, el problema es que no puedo lograrlo y no se bien cual es el problema

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'com.mercadopago.android.px:checkout:4.+'
}
```

Agregué esa dependencia en mi Gradle y ya poseo el SDK de Mercado Pago.

Luego, copié un codigo del apartado Mobile Checkout en Developers (Sitio de Mercado Pago), el cual es el siguiente :

```
Preference preference = new Preference();

Item item = new Item();
item.setId("1234")
    .setTitle("Blue shirt")
    .setQuantity(10)
    .setCategoryId("ARS")
    .setUnitPrice((float) 150);

Payer payer = new Payer();
payer.setEmail("john@yourdomain.com");

preference.setPayer(payer);
preference.appendItem(item);
preference.save();
```

Ahora viene el problema, obtengo los siguientes errores

- Cannot resolve constructor 'Preference()'
- Cannot resolve constructor 'Item()'
- Cannot resolve method 'setPayer' in 'Preference'
- Cannot resolve method 'appendItem' in 'Preference'
- Cannot resolve method 'save' in 'Preference'

Entonces, es como si la clase Preference no se encuentra en la SDK de Mercado Pago y la clase Item si pertenece al Package de Mercado Pago pero no tiene esos metodos

Pues si pude importar la clase Item con

```
import com.mercadopago.android.px.model.Item;
```

Alguna sugerencia o consejo?!
O si conocen un tutorial donde se aprenda a usar el Mobile Checkout, desde ya, Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Hola es un poco mas complejo que esto, dado que para obtener la preferencia tendrías que generar el json de pago. Para ello tenes que armar el json con todos esos datos en la documentación podes encontrar los datos [acá](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/reference/preferences/_checkout_preferences/post) podes encontrar los campos, una ves obtenida la preferencia de pago que es una clave tipo "202809963-a2201f8d-11cb-443f-adf6-de5a42eed67d" con ella y el public_key,

```
new MercadoPagoCheckout.Builder(public_key, checkoutPreferenceId).build().startPayment(this, MERCADOPAGOTASKID);
```

Luego tendrías que onActivityResult con el MERCADOPAGOTASKID

verificas el resultado del regreso MercadoPagoCheckout.PAYMENT_RESULT_CODE
y obtenés el

```
Payment pago = (Payment) data.getSerializableExtra(MercadoPagoCheckout.EXTRA_PAYMENT_RESULT);
```

Dentro de este objeto tenes todos los datos del pago.
la versión actual es 4.53.1 para el día de hoy esta versión tiene un problema con el kotlin que varias funciones están obsoletas. y tenes que pasar al lazycheckout, estoy recogiendo info de eso versión aun no lo tengo.
saludos
espero que te ayude.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución pero por qué no puede resolver los constructores y métodos indicados, te sugerimos revisar [ask], saludos.